# jQuery select only hovered item, with same class

Tags: html, jquery, css

I am creating simple jQuery Project, but I am in trouble, I can't figure out how I can solve this problem. I've created three boxes, then I hover around these boxes I want box text to appear, yes it's working, but I want to appear only box text which was hovered (mousseentered), now it appears all of them, for example if I hover on first box, I want to only first box text appear, all the boxes have same class name, and it is needed

```js
$('.three_box_inner').mouseenter(function(){
  $('.text').css({
    'display':'block',
  })

})
```

```css
.three_box{
display:flex;

}

.three_box_inner{
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  background-color:red;
  margin-left:20px;
}
.text {
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='three_box'>
  <div class='three_box_inner'>
    <div class='text'>
      text
    </div>
    </div>
      <div class='three_box_inner'>
        <div class='text'>
      text
    </div>
    </div>
      <div class='three_box_inner'>
        <div class='text'>
      text
    </div>
    </div>
  <div>
```

Comment: There's absolutely no need for JS. All you need is CSS and the `:hover` pseudo selector. `.three_box_inner:hover .text { /*do your magic here*/ }`

Comment: i want to do this with js, for practice ;)

Comment: Well, I posted two examples, one using CSS and one using JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's absolutely no need for JS. All you need is CSS and the `:hover` pseudo selector.

```
.three_box_inner:hover .text {
  display: block;
}
```

Example:

```css
.three_box {
  display: flex;
}

.three_box_inner {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.text {
  background: gold;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.three_box_inner:hover .text {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class='three_box'>
  <div class='three_box_inner'>
    <div class='text'>
      text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='three_box_inner'>
    <div class='text'>
      text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='three_box_inner'>
    <div class='text'>
      text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you really want to preserve the visible state:
Notice how the CSS remained almost the same, just instead of `:hover` you can use a `.is-hover` and change those classes on the parent element using jQuery's `.removeClass()` and `.addClass()`

```js
const $box = $(".three_box_inner");

$box.on("mouseenter", function() {
  $box.not(this).removeClass("is-hover");
  $(this).addClass("is-hover");
});
```

```css
.three_box {
  display: flex;
}

.three_box_inner {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.text {
  background: gold;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.three_box_inner.is-hover .text {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class='three_box'>
  <div class='three_box_inner'>
    <div class='text'>
      text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='three_box_inner'>
    <div class='text'>
      text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='three_box_inner'>
    <div class='text'>
      text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use find() or children and toggle() inside `hover()` which is triigered by both `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`

```js
$('.three_box_inner').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('.text').toggle()
})
```

```css
.three_box {
  display: flex;
}

.three_box_inner {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.text {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='three_box'>
  <div class='three_box_inner'>
    <div class='text'>
      text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='three_box_inner'>
    <div class='text'>
      text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='three_box_inner'>
    <div class='text'>
      text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
```